# My array changes in IDLE but not when I import the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys so I wrote some code as a nested loop for school, which iterates over multiple lists inside a list which have grades for different subjects and then creates a new list with the averages of each of those courses like so.

```
>>> new_list = []

>>> for x in range(len(grades)):
        sum_of_grades = 0
        for i in range(len(grades[x])):
            sum_of_grades = sum_of_grades + grades[x][i]
        new_list.append(sum_of_grades / len(grades[x]))


>>> new_list
[75.0, 85.0, 90.0]
```

It works perfectly with no issues when I run this code in Idle. The issue is when I create a function on another file. It keeps saying new list is not defined.

```
def averages(grades):
    ''' (list of a list of numbers) -> list of float

    Return a new list in which each item is the average of the grades
    in the inner list at the corresponding position

    >>> averages = [[70, 75, 80], [70, 80, 90, 100], [80, 100]]
    [75.0, 85.0, 90.0]
    '''
    new_list = []

    for x in range(len(grades)):
        sum_of_grades = 0
        for i in range(len(grades[x])):
            sum_of_grades = sum_of_grades + grades[x][i]
        new_list.append(sum_of_grades / len(grades[x]))
    print(new_list)
```

Any explanation to help me out would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    new_list
NameError: name 'new_list' is not defined
```

I created a `insideloops.py` file where I run the bottom code of:

```
def averages(grades):
```

And then i save the file and run module from idle and then call the function in idle with `averages = [[70, 75, 80], [70, 80, 90, 100], [80, 100]]`.

I tried to troubleshoot as well using new_list as a global var and importing it into the function and it looks like nothing is being appended to the list.

**Thanks for all the help everyone. I was calling the function like an array instead of like a function. **

How I was calling it:

```
averages = [[70, 75, 80], [70, 80, 90, 100], [80, 100]]
```

How I called it when it started to work:

```
averages = ([[70, 75, 80], [70, 80, 90, 100], [80, 100]])
```

Comment: How exactly are you executing this function? (e.g. F5 in IDLE, cmd, etc.)

Comment: Which line does it say that on?

Comment: Executing from idle in a .py document by clicknig run module

Comment: Could you post your error in the question, it will help illuminate the issue.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    new_list
NameError: name 'new_list' is not defined

Comment: Python variables are local to the scope they are created in. Are you calling the function in one line and then trying to print new_list in another?

Comment: Like `>>>averages(myGrades)` and then the next line (in IDLE) `>>>print(new_list)`?

Comment: @AustinA i am calling the function in one like like so
averages = [[70, 75, 80], [70, 80, 90, 100], [80, 100]]

Comment: The function worked for me. You must be doing something else wrong

Comment: Ok I think i see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you add into your question exactly what you're typing into IDLE?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 ya I agree with you. I tested it in idle before i wrote the function on another py doc and it worked

Comment: It's possible you're redefining the variable `averages`. (functions in Python are first class objects)

Comment: That doesn't explain the error though.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 lol i was calling the function wrong, i was callnig it like an array isntead of using the () my gawd

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the problem :)